# MATLAB matrix division

Tags: matlab

Why does A/J yield a result? (I was expecting an error because the matrix J was not square.)

```
A = [1 3; 4 5];
J = [4,5; 6,7; 8,9];
A/J 
ans = 2×3    
    3.7500         0   -1.7500
    1.0000         0   -0.0000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `ans * J == I`. `/` is the matrix division and solves the systems of linear equations `X * J = I` for `X`. `./` is the element-wise division.

You can find examples and read about it [here.](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html)

Comment: @ChrisLuengo But Matlab knows matrix division and this is Matlab code. `A/B` calculates the solution for `X * B=A`

Comment: @ChrisLuengo The answer is in my first sentence: _"Because `ans * J == I`"_

Comment: @ThomasSablik. i edited question to use "A" instead of "I" to avoid confusion with identity matrix. thanks.